# bootstrap modal remote data ajax is duplicating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap v3.3.0 modal window and having issues removing it. I have a list of orders and next to each one I have a button to see more details.  When this button is clicked, a modal window is opened. An ajax call is then made once the modal window has opened.

So basically the ajax call below is made when the modal window has loaded:

```
    $("#footable").on('click', '.btn', function() {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {


            $(".modal-title").text("Items Order No:" + id);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'url' + id,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    var tbody = $("<tbody id='modal-content'>");
                    if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {

                        //build the table rows and append them to the main table
                        for (var g = 0; g < data.length; g++) {
                            if (data[g].quantity != 0) {
                                row = '<tr id=+data[g].id+>';
                                row += '<td>' + data[g].id + '</td>';
                                row += '<td>' + data[g].description + '</td>';
                                row += '<td>' + data[g].price + '</td>';
                                row += '<td>' + data[g].quantity + '</td>';
                                row += '</tr>';
                                tbody.append(row);
                            }
                        }

                        tbody.append("<tbody />");
                        tbody.appendTo("#footable1");

                    } else {
                        var row = '<tr>';
                        row += '<td>No items returned!</td>';
                        row += '</tr>';
                        tbody.append(row);
                        tbody.append("<tbody />");
                        tbody.appendTo("#footable1");

                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    //console.log(e.message);
                }
            });

        }).modal('show');
    });
```

This is how I try to remove it:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal').find("#modal-content").empty();;

});
```

Here is the html for the modal:

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                                 <table class="footable1" id="footable1" data-page-size="5">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Order ID
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Item
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Quantity
                                            </th>
                                            <th data-hide="phone">
                                                Unit Price
                                            </th>
                                            <th data-hide="phone">
                                                Total Price
                                            </th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   <!--the body will be appended dynamically here -->
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="11">
                                                <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>

                       </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="modalClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
```

The issue I am having is when I open a new modal, it seems to keep the content of the previous ajax calls made. For Order ID 3, it will keep order ID 1 & 2 order items until the screen is refreshed.

Does somebody know how I can solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can copy html from your modal($("#myModal").html()) and create new modal at calling method. After close, remove this modal.

Comment: thanks  - are you saying I should create the modal on the fly and then remove the html? I thought there would be a standard way of doing this kind of things?